# How to change the axis values of matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 11x9 numpy matrix of `float`s which I would like to visualize as a "heatmap".

Data example:

```
>>> print(result)
[[ 0.11686587  0.27755644  0.5768039   0.65205843  0.75033201  0.8145197
   0.77202302  0.64099159  0.39442231]
 [ 0.27888446  0.55511288  0.6728641   0.77335104  0.85391766  0.91633466
   0.94510846  0.96901284  0.9729969 ]
 [ 0.55599823  0.68171757  0.77512174  0.89287295  0.937583    0.94643648
   0.96768482  0.97742364  0.97919433]
 [ 0.6644533   0.76803896  0.895529    0.94510846  0.96370075  0.97211155
   0.97786631  0.97919433  0.97919433]
 [ 0.77290837  0.86586985  0.94953519  0.96945551  0.97698097  0.97786631
   0.97786631  0.97919433  0.97919433]
 [ 0.85214697  0.94245241  0.9747676   0.97653829  0.97786631  0.97786631
   0.97919433  0.97919433  0.97919433]
 [ 0.94200974  0.96724214  0.97565294  0.97653829  0.97609562  0.97786631
   0.97919433  0.97919433  0.97919433]
 [ 0.95883134  0.97255423  0.97609562  0.97742364  0.97786631  0.97786631
   0.97919433  0.97919433  0.97919433]
 [ 0.97166888  0.97343958  0.9747676   0.96104471  0.97830899  0.97919433
   0.97919433  0.97919433  0.97919433]
 [ 0.9729969   0.97565294  0.9747676   0.97255423  0.97078353  0.97919433
   0.97919433  0.97919433  0.97919433]
 [ 0.97078353  0.97565294  0.9747676   0.97078353  0.96989819  0.97919433
   0.97919433  0.97919433  0.97919433]]
```

So far I've plotted it by using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.matshow(result)
plt.show()
```

[image: Heatplot]

The problem is that the axis are numbered from 0 to 10 and from 0 to 9. I would like to number them logarithmically from 10^-5 to 10^5 etc.

Is it somehow possible? I don't mean the axis labels but the displayed values on axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set any value of the tick labels using the function [set_xticklabels](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels) and [set_yticklabels](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels). It takes a list of strings to assign to each tick. For example:

```
plt.set_xticklabels(["10^-5", "10^-4", "..."])
```

Comment: this actually works only on axis objects, but it helped me to google the right thing, thnkas